# Prove that the minimum of row sums of a nonnegative symmetric matrix is preserved

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let A be an nxn adjacency (nonnegative, irreducible and symmetric) matrix with zeros on the diagonal. Denote i-th row sum of A^k as r^(k)_i, where k>=1. I want to prove that if r_j=min_i{r_i} for some j, then r(k)_j=min_i{r^(k)_i}, in other words the minimum row sum is preserved.
I know that this is true only based on intuition. It would be much appreciated if someone can give me some idea for a formal proof.

Comment: This is math and not programming. Please ask such question on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is my first time using Stackoverflow. No wonder no one replied to my post regarding the question. Thanks a lot @hivert.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't stand. This can be seen in terms of graphs. Matrix A is adjacency matrix of un-directed graph. For A it hold that element (i,j) of matrix A^k represent number of paths between nodes i and j of length k, and sum of a i'th row means number of paths between i and any other node of length k.

Assumption is based on number of neighbours which is local measure. Simple example where there are more nodes with same min r_i, and different r^2_i.

```
    B----C
   /     |\
  /      | \
 /       |  \
A        D   D
 \       |  /
  \      | /
   \     |/
    B----C

r_A = r_B = r_D = 2 = min
r_C = 3
r^2_A = 4 = 2*A-B-C, 2*A-B-A
r^2_B = 5 = B-A-B, 2*B-C-D, B-A-B, B-C-B
r^2_C = 6
r^2_D = 6
```

Comment: Thank you. You're right. It has to satisfy a constraint. I'm interested in the case where A is the adjacency matrix of a regular graph, i.e. a graph with all vertices have the same degree. Now, without loss of generality, one edge is removed from the graph. There are only two rows with minimum row sums and the remaining row sums are identical. In this case, the statement should be true.

Comment: If d is regular graph node degree, than r^k_i = d^k. In case of one edge removed, these 2 nodes will have smaller r^k_i than other nodes. That can be seen by creating DFS (with returning) on regular graph, and pruning branches where removed edge is used. For there 2 nodes one of 'master' branches is pruned and these trees will have less leaves than for other nodes. To prove it, similar construction has to be used.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the construction but it is not straightforward to turn it into a formal proof.